# Update dom without refresh the page in react 16

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, state, render, reload

So, I've been looking for a way to render this img tag on my dom without refresh the screen. But I didn't find a definitive answer on how to do that! I mean, in a natural way, with react library and without change a lot of things.

So, when I click this div, it calls a method

```
<div ref={(ref) => this.refProjectImageCenter = ref} onClick={(e) => this.selectImage(e, this.refProjectImageCenter)} >
  <img src="images/projects/new-account.png" alt="new account" />
</div>
```

And in this method, I update my state with a new img element (not sure if it's the best way to do it tho)

```
selectImage(e: any ,  el: HTMLDivElement) 
{
        e.preventDefault(); // This is not working
        this.setState({ selected_img: <img src={el.children[0].getAttribute("src")} /> });
}
```

And the state will update this part of the DOM

```
<div className="image detail">
                {this.state.selected_img}
</div>
```

It renders the img indeed, but the page flashes(refresh), and I want to do that asynchronously. It's possible to do that with react? If it's not, how everybody is doing it right now? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The whole page flashes or just the `img` you're rerendering?

Comment: I guess that's because you are making new request for image. You could check onLoad property of image to show a loader until image is rendered?

Comment: The whole page flashes, It's re-rendering the whole page. 
And about the loader, the img takes 1 second to show. And even with the loader, it will still reload the page right?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem Henry and Shubham. I was updating the css class of the main html tag:

```
this.refMasterDOM.classList.remove("active");
```

Inside the method `componentWillUpdate()`. I removed this line and it stopped refreshing the page with sestate command. Although I don't know why.